# Is cassandra really a NoSQL Database?

Tags: cassandra

I'm new to cassandara and NoSql Database. as per my understanding when you say it is NoSQL it means it should accept all data when you insert values(it is schema free). i.e. I have created a table in cassandra, it contains 5 fields. First insert query I inserted only 5 values, it is success. Next I tried 6 values, it throws error saying there is Unmatched column names/values (6th field). If cassandra is NoSQL then that 6th field should be inserted into Table.

I did this Google. Few people suggested saying user alter Query to change schema. If that is the case, I can use alter schema in SQL also. Then why I need to go to NoSQL?

Is my understanding is correct?

> Unmatched column names/values
> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unmatched column names/values

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL - The definition of NoSQL is broader than you think.  Cassandra is a wide column store:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide-column_store

Comment: And not all NoSQL DBs are schema-less.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Cassandra is a NoSQL database. A NoSQL database can be broadly defined as a database which stores and maintains data in non relational way(No SQL), can store web scale data easily, can scale out and is generally distributed. Cassandra ticks all the boxes for to be called as a NoSQL database.

Coming back to your question regarding requirement of a schema. Cassandra used to provide (still provide as deprecated feature) to add columns on the go using `thrift` API. Thrift API is going to be completely removed in Cassandra 4.0. Cassandra now supports schema based CQL.

You can still design your table to add columns dynamically using CQL, like

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.table_name (
partition_key  text,
column_name   text,
column_value   text,

PRIMARY KEY ((partition_key),column_name));
```

Now you can group all rows consisting of `column_name` and `column_value` with `partition_key` and rows sorted by `column_name`.